# Textjoin values of column B if duplicates are present in column A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, powerquery

I want to consolidate the data of column B into a single cell ONLY IF the index (ie., Column A) is duplicated.

For example:

[image]

Currently, I'm doing manually for each duplicated index by using the following formula:

**=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,B4:B6)**

Is there a better way to do this all at once?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for my data

`=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A:A=A2,B:B,"")),"")`

Make sure to enter this formula as an array formula by pressing CTRL+Shift+Enter after typing it in the cell. Then you can drag the formula down to apply it to other cells.

Answer (score 1):

There may easier way but you can try this formula-

```
=BYROW(A2:A17,LAMBDA(p,IF(INDEX(MAP(A2:A17,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(A2:INDEX(A2:A17,ROW(x)-1)=x)))),ROW(p)-1,1)=1,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(B2:B17,A2:A17=p)),"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Be aware the OP requested to concatenate the values *only IF* in col `A` there is a repetition. Your  current solution returns a value also when there is no repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Using `REDUCE` might be possible for a more succinct solution, though try this for now:

`=BYROW(A2:A17,LAMBDA(ζ,LET(α,A2:A17,IF((COUNTIF(α,ζ)>1)*(COUNTIF(INDEX(α,1):ζ,ζ)=1),TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(B2:B17,α=ζ)),""))))`

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of alternatives about how to solve it:

Using `XMATCH`/`UNIQUE`

```
=LET(A, A2:A17, ux, UNIQUE(A),idx, FILTER(XMATCH(ux, A), COUNTIF(A, ux)>1), 
 MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A)), LAMBDA(s, IF(ISNA(XMATCH(s, idx)), "", TEXTJOIN(",",, 
 FILTER(B2:B17, A=INDEX(A,s)))))))
```

or using `SMALL`/`INDEX` to identify the first element of the repetition:

```
=LET(A, A2:A17, n, ROWS(A), s, SEQUENCE(n), 
 MAP(A, s, LAMBDA(aa,ss, LET(f, FILTER(B2:B17, A=aa), IF((ROWS(f)>1) 
   * (INDEX(s, SMALL(IF(A=aa, s, n+1),1))=ss), TEXTJOIN(",",, f), "")))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample output file]

### Explanation

#### `XMATCH` and `UNIQUE`

The main idea here is to identify the first unique elements of column `A` via `ux`, and find their corresponding index position in `A` via `XMATCH(ux, A)`. It is an array of the same size as `ux`. Then `COUNTIF(A, ux)>1)` returns an array of the same size as `XMATCH` output indicating where we have a repetition.

Here is the intermediate result:

```
XMATCH(ux, A) COUNTIF(A, ux)>1)
1             FALSE
2             FALSE
3             TRUE
6             FALSE
7             TRUE
9             TRUE
11            FALSE
12            TRUE
15            FALSE
16            FALSE
```

so `FILTER` takes only the rows form the first column where the second column is `TRUE`, i.e the index position (`idx`) where the repetition starts. For our sample it will be: `{3;7;9;12}`.

Now we iterate over the sequence of index positions (`s`) via `MAP` . If `s` is found in `idx` via `XMATCH` (also `XLOOKUP(s, idx, TRUE, FALSE)` can be used for the same purpose) then we join the values of column `B` filtered by column `A` equal to `INDEX(A,s)`.

#### `SMALL` and `INDEX`

This is a *more flexible approach* because in the case we want to do the concatenation in another position of the repetition you just need to specify the order and the formula doesn't change.

We iterate via `MAP` through elements of column `A` and index position (`s`). The name `f` has the filtered values from column `B` where column `A` is equal to a given value of the iteration `aa`. We need to identify only filtered rows with repetition, so the first condition `ROWS(f) > 1` ensures it.

The second condition identifies only the first element of the repetition:

```
INDEX(s, SMALL(IF(A=aa, s, n+1),1))=ss
```

The second argument of `SMALL` indicates we want the first smallest value, but it could be the second, third, etc.

Where `A` is equal to `aa`, `IF` assigns the corresponding value of the sequence (remember `IF` works as an array formula), if not then it assigns a value that will never be the smallest one, for example, `n+1`, where `n` represents the number of rows of column `B`. `SMALL` returns the smallest index position. If the current index position `ss` is not the smallest one, the conditions `FALSE`.

Finally, we do a `TEXTJOIN` only when both conditions are met (we multiply them to ensure an `AND` condition).